# JavaCC grammar and .jjt

Tags: java, parsing, javacc

I need to write the grammar for a program.

### Program:

```
app(name : 'App1') { 

  View(id: top) { 
    Label(id: l1, text: 'Hi') 
    Button(id: b1, text: 'Press')
    Button(id: b2, text: 'Exit')
    Panel(id: row3, orientation: 'verticall') { 
      Label(id: l2, text : 'Name') 
      Text(id: t1, text : 'Enter text')
    }
  }

}
```

### Grammar:

```
/**
 * JJTree template file created by SF JavaCC plugin 1.5.17+ wizard for JavaCC 1.5.0+
 */
options
{

}

PARSER_BEGIN(MADLParser)
package ui.parser;

public class MADLParser extends MADLParserBase
{}

PARSER_END(MADLParser)

//  =================================================================
//  Define the token manager.
//  =================================================================
TOKEN_MGR_DECLS :
{
  void CommonTokenAction(Token t)
  {}
}


TOKEN :
{
   < OPAR  : "(" > 
 | < CPAR  : ")" >
 | < COL   : ":" >
 | < APOS   : "'" >
 | < OBR   : "{" >
 | < CBR   : "}" >
 | < COMMA : "," >
 | < SCOL  : ";" >
 | < APP : "app" >
 | < NAME : "name">
 | < VIEW : "View" >
 | < LABEL : "Label" >
 | < BUTTON : "Button" >
 | < PANEL : "Panel" >
 | < TEXT : "Text">
 | < PAID  : "id">
 | < PATEXT : "text">
 | < PAORIENTATION : "orientation" >
 | < PABACKGROUND : "background" >
 | < PAALIGN : "align" >
 | < PACOLOR : "color" >
 | < WIDGETNAME : ( "Label"  | "Button" | "Text" ) > 

 | < PARAMETERTYPE : ( "text" | "orientation" | "background" | "align" | "color" ) >

 | < ALPHANUMERIC    : ("_" | <LETTER>) ("_" | <ALPHANUM>)* >
 | < #DIGIT    : ["0"-"9"] >
 | < #LETTER   : ["a"-"z","A"-"Z"] >
 | < #ALPHANUM : <LETTER> | <DIGIT> >  

 | < EOL :
    "\r\n"
  | "\r"
  | "\n" >

}

SimpleNode Start() #Start:
{}
{
   MainProgram()
  < EOF >
  {
    return jjtThis;
  }
}

void MainProgram() :
{}
{
     < APP > < OPAR > < NAME > < COL > < APOS > < ALPHANUMERIC > < APOS > < CPAR > < OBR >
     < EOL >
      MainView()
      < EOL >
      < CBR > 
}

void MainView() :
{}
{
     < VIEW > < OPAR > < PAID > < COL > < ALPHANUMERIC > < CPAR > < OBR >
     < EOL >
     Widgets()
     < EOL >
}

void Widgets() :
{}
{
     < WIDGETNAME > < OPAR > < PAID > < COL > < ALPHANUMERIC >
      ( < COMMA > < PARAMETERTYPE > < COL > < APOS > < ALPHANUMERIC > < APOS > < CPAR > )* 
}
```

Once i tried compile this file using `JavaCC` i got an error in the `MADLParser.java` generated file.

I can't figure out the problem in it.

Comment: Please add the text of the error, the text of the procedure in MADLParser.java that has the error, and indicate which line the error is associated to.

Comment: the error I am getting is 'The hierarchy of the type MADLParser is inconsistent'. Im not sure if this will help. thanks

Comment: Does MADLParserBase.class exist in your bin directory?

Comment: i don't have a bin folder in my project. I'm am executing this file in a eclipse plugin project.

Comment: Look on your disk for the bin directory.  In any case that error seems to come up when the super class can not be found.  There are several stack exchange questions related to "the hierarchy of type x is inconsistent".

Comment: hi Theodore, i was able to solve this issue. thanks.How do I verify that the grammar I wrote match to the program I have. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Is the language you are trying to parse described by a grammar already, or my some other means.

Comment: I am not sure if the language I'm trying to parse describe the grammar. I want to make sure that the grammar i wrote is matching to the language. thanks appreciate a reply

Comment: If you have a formal description of the language, then there are ways you can prove that the grammar is equivalent. E.g. if the language is described by a regular expression, you should be able to either prove that the grammar describes the same language or find a counter-example. However if the only description of the language is informal, I know of now way to show the grammar matches the description, other than to review the grammar and to test the derived parser.